# Gnu make : using content of file as recipe

Tags: makefile, dependencies, gnu-make

Consider having a makefile, which can generate some files using generating lines listed in a file. For example file 001 using first line, 002 using second line, etc.

This file can be changed (it has it's own dependences, but this doesn't metter).
If some lines in this file changed, appropriate files should be remade. But other files shouldn't.

The solution I found is this one: for every file there is flag-file which content is generating line it was made last time. After remaking file with  generating lines, i check all this file, and remove them if line changed. So files which have dependences on removed files will be remade, and other files won't. But this works too slow if use msys-make.

Can you suggest any other solution, which doesn't need many extra calls to file system and executable runs.

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear.  What is the format of this file, and how does it specify the dependencies to pick up?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your description correctly, what you're describing is a Makefile which depends on another file that is functionally a Makefile but for unknown reasons uses a different format.

Turn that file into Makefile format and [include](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html) it into the original Makefile.  (If you're using GNU Make.)

Comment: Converting it to makefile format doesn't solve problem. The problem is detecting recipe change, if thinking about it, as makefile. Can make do it in some easy way?

Comment: @user2281791 GNU Make's include will do that for you automatically. Read the manual.

Comment: Recipe change will not cause remaking of target.

Comment: They will in makepp, which always considers **all** dependencies, not just newer input files.

Comment: You'd need to make the included makefile a dependency of your target.

Answer (score 0):

We have what may be similar to your problem.  We have xml files, say `foobar.xml` which contains the dependencies for `foobar.out`

```
<files>
  <file>a</file>
  <file>b</file>
  <file>c</file>
</files>
```

We decided to adhere to this simple layout, so we don't need to parse xml.  We use [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/) (because we got fed up with gmake not noticing dependencies like changed commands).  This gives us the builtin `&sed` command (the expression is actually Perl programming, but as you see, you don't need to get into it much).  Here's what we do with three simple substitutions for the three kinds of lines:

```
%.d: %.xml
    &sed 's!<files>!$(stem).out: \\! || s!<file>(.+)</file>!$$1 \\! || s!</files>!!' \
        $(input) -o $(output)

include foobar.d
```

This produces `foobar.d` which we then include:

```
foobar.out: \
  a \
  b \
  c \
```

Stackoverflow is swallowing the last empty line here, which avoids having to worry about the trailing backslash.